# PHP mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code

```
class Db_conn {
    private $sn = 'localhost';
    private $un = 'root';
    private $up = '';
    public function connect(string $db_n){
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->sn, $this->un, $this->up, $db_n);
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Připojení se nezdařilo: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        } else {
            return $conn;
        }
    }
}
```

And this code

```
public function update($query){
    $dbconn = new Db_conn();
    if (mysqli_query($dbconn, $query)) {
        return True;
    } else {
        return False;
    }
}
```

And on this line `if (mysqli_query($dbconn, $query)) {`
it says there is an error.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in D:\xampp\htdocs\purkiada2\content\Db_parser.inc.php on line 21

Comment: This: `if (mysqli_query($dbconn, $query))`. You're literally creating an instance of `Db_conn` and passing that in when you should probably be using your connection method `if (mysqli_query($dbconn->connect('your_database_name'), $query))`.

Comment: where you select your DB, How you pointed your DB

Comment: Thanks I used that solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) expects a mysqli connection, but you give it a `Db_conn` object. This is what the error message says.

You must first connect and then give this (mysqli) connection to `mysqli_query`, e.g.

```
public function update($query){
    $dbconn = new Db_conn();
    $conn = $dbconn->connect();
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        return True;
    } else {
        return False;
    }
}
```